# nodejs oauth2 token regeneration help needed

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, oauth-2.0

I am doing my first test application on nodejs. It is very simple. Fetch data from an api and display it on the browser. Here are the steps I followed.

1. I use express for web and request for getting API results.
2. First I request a token from the API server using Oauth2 Client credentials method.
3. I get a token and pass it to the resource URL and get the results.
4. Display it to the browser using pug (Was Jade) template engine.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var tools = require('./tools');
    var app = express();
    var request = require('request');
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');

    // Get the token key 
    tools.generateToken(function(response){
        token = response;
    });


    //Index Page routing
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       //res.send('Hello World '+token);
        var request = require('request');
        request('URL?access_token='+token+'&n=10&pgno=2', function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            res.render('index', { layout : 'layout', json: JSON.parse(body) });
          }

        })



    });

    var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

      var host = server.address().address
      var port = server.address().port

      console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

    })
```

Everything seems to be working well. But once the token is expired I can't retrieve any results (it is obvious). But I don't know when to get the new token. When should I recall the token generation function?

Also, is there a way to track API data changes without browser refresh? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: any route that provides access to resource that requires authentication should have an auth middleware, this is where you'd check the validity of the token and allow the request through if the token is legit. Typically you'd update the expiry timestamp of the token in your db/cache here to prevent your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reqclient](https://github.com/mrsarm/reqclient#oauth-2-authorization), it's a small client library on top of `request` that allow you to handle the OAuth2 token refresh process automatically, so if the OAuth2 server gives you an expiration time in the same response, `reqclient` will know when it has to request a new one without any intervention.

Also has other nice features like *cURL* logging to know how the requests are made, *Promise*  objects to handle the responses, etc. It's also available to install with `npm`.

This is an example of how to create a `RequestClient` object to handle request against an API, and also tells to the module who is the OAuth2 server, and what are the credentials to get a token:

```
var client = new RequestClient({
  baseUrl: "https://api.example.com/myapi"
  ,debugRequest:true, debugResponse:true   // (optional) this activate curl logging
  ,oauth2: {
    baseUrl: 'https://auth.example.com/oauth2'
    ,auth: {
      user: 'client123'        // The username, also called "client_id"
      ,pass: 'thePass123'       // The password, also called "client_secret"
    }
  }
});

client.get("home-reports")      // First will try to login with OAuth2, then /home-reports 
.then(client.get("messages"));  // Will reuse the previous token obtained if it's not expired yet, otherwise it will request a new one first
```

Both requests will return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) objects, so you have to handle with `then` and `catch` what to do with them. Anyway, because the logging was activated with `debugRequest:true, debugResponse:true` (optional), all requests and responses will be logged whithin the console like this:

```
[Requesting token]-> -X POST https://auth.example.com/oauth2/token -u ${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET} -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
[Response   token]<- Status 200 - {"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAsdsAdggT5c0EkLng4yBEwght3bfDGf47hbSk3","expires_in":3456543}
[Requesting home-reports]-> https://api.example.com/myapi/home-reports -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
[Response   home-reports]<- Status 200 - {"sales":53434.53,"purchases":12984.04}
[Requesting messages]-> https://api.example.com/myapi/messages -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
[Response   messages]<- Status 200 - {"messages":[]}
```